# Create a polynomial from a list of coefficients

Tags: list-manipulation, polynomials, coefficients

First I have to extract coefficients from a polynomial.Then I have to make a polynomial from by given list and show that they are identical. So I tried like this:

```
f[x_] := 3 x^3 - 7 x^2 + 6; 

coefficientlist = Table[Coefficient[f[x], x, i], {i, 0, 3}];(*It also can be do by CoefficientList[]*) 

poly = x^Range[0, 3]*coefficientlist // TraditionalForm
```

But here I got problem to create the polynomial from my `coefficientlist`. Can Anyone help me to figure out this. Any hints or solution will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at ref / CoefficientList then Properties and relations 3rd example.

Comment: Yes.i got it.Thanks @kuba